# How can I hide the calendar sidebar in iClouds calendar app

Tags: calendar, icloud

I somehow activated this sidebar list of calendars:

[image: Calendar List sidebar]

And it is really annoying me, as it limits the space the calendar itself takes up. As you can see, I only have one calendar active anyway, so I'd like to hide that sidebar. But I cannot find any close / hide button, and in the settings of the calendar, there is no possibility to do so either.

How can I hide this sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea if I just didn't see this before or it was added recently, but there is a button on the bottom row:

[image: Bottom Row Button]

Clicking it toggles the sidebar with the calendars.